# Adding new view resolver

Tags: spring-boot, module, thymeleaf

I created a module in a Spring-boot project and I want to redirect a controller to a view in this module. I can't find a solution and I've been trying different options. Now, I'm adding template resolvers in my `WebMvcConfig` and the one to the root templates  is working but I can't make the other one work. Any idea please?

Here is the `WebMvcConfig`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateModuleResolver() {

    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("espmonitor/src/main/resources/templates/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateRootResolver() {

    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return templateResolver;
}


@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateModuleResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateRootResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return viewResolver;
}
```

The view controller is:

```
@RequestMapping("/index_esp_monitor")
public String espMonitor(Model model){

return "index_esp_monitor";
}
```

My project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work and I'm going to show the solution here just in case someone is trying to do a similar thing.

I was trying to have many applications within one project and trying to have each application in a different module.

First, I created the modules in the project and add an additional module as a selector. Then I remove the `src` folder from the project and add the modules to the project `pom`

```
<modules>
    <module>espmonitor</module>
    <module>seed</module>
    <module>selector</module>
</modules>
```

And the `pom` of each module contains:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>SeedCert</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.niab</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
```

The project structure is as follows, the module `selector` will contain the indexes to the other modules.

[image]

The `Application.java` is configured to scan the configurations of the other modules.

```
@ComponentScan({
    "com.niab.config",
    "com.niab.selector.controller"
})
```

Each module has a com.niab.config package for the specific scanning

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way of doing it, but it's quite a simple solution and it does what I need.